# Why does the redux-persist package cause RTK queries isFetching state to remain stuck on true?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, redux-persist

I am wondering, why does the redux-persist package cause RTK queries isFetching state to remain stuck on true?

In our application I have observed that having redux-persist configured in our store to run with all RTK queries, it causing the isFetching property from the query hook to remain true at all times unless the session storage is cleared.

We want to use this because it helps track when requests in are flight.

Is this expected or this is a bug?